# Variable Plotted in 3d Space

Tags: plotting, data

I am trying to plot dose rate in 3d space in terms of r, theta and z.
None of the variables are functions of each other they are just arrays of points with the following sizes: 
Dose 220x35
r 220x35
z 220x11
theta 220x20
I want to plot the dose rate in 3d space with a colorbar to indicate the value.

thanks

Comment: You probably want `ListContourPlot3D`

Comment: My guess is that you probably want to interpolate and use `DensityPlot3D`.  Or you could use `ListDensityPlot3D[Transpose@{r, theta, z, dose}]`, which would plot the data without the coordinate change you probably desire.  See the docs for `Interpolation` and the two plotting functions for examples.

Comment: How do you treat missing columns  in `z` (columns 12 thru 35) and `theta` (columns 21 thru 35)?